# git merge does not trigger pre-merge-commit or post-merge hooks with option --no-commit

Tags: git

I am currently in the process to add some automation after a user pulls or merge into the current branch (e.g. update user settings, build updated dependencies). I read the hook documentation and found out that pre-merge-commit / post-merge hooks would do that for me. So, the in the use case that we have no merge conflicts, i.e. the merge was successful, both hooks should trigger.

This works fine as long as the merge creates no changes on the working copy (as result of the merge). But if there are changes (e.g. a new file has been added) and I run the git merge command with --no-commit option, both pre-merge-commit and post-merge hooks are NOT executed.

At least with the pre-merge-commit hook I would expect to get the hook fired as the hook is triggered before the commit!

Is this by design? Is there another way to trigger a script after a merge has been successful  ignoring the option if I want a commit afterall?

Thanks!

Comment: "No commit" means just that. A pre-commit hook, whether pre-regular or pre-merge, happens just before the commit, as part of the commit—so, it should not and does not happen here. The hooks should run later, if and when you choose to commit the result.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The problem is that the hook is not executed. A default merge is with the commit option enabled and in that scenario, both hooks are executed. But when I just want to merge without a finishing commit, i.e. --no-commit, the pre-merge-hook is not executed. But as of my understanding, it should as it runs after the successful merge but before the commit. And the post-merge hook is not executed at all. Hope I made the issue more clear.

Comment: The pre-merge-commit hook *should* run when you run `git merge --continue` to finish the merge. Ideally it should even run when you use `git commit` to finish the merge. If it doesn't run for *either* case, that seems like a definite bug; if it does run for `git merge --continue` but not for a `git commit` that commits a merge, that seems like a bug as well, but perhaps more arguable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that the documentation is not very clear about when it should be executed, but I think that at least the commit process has to begin. Here is why:

> `pre-merge-commit` [...] is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and
> before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit

First part is clear, merge must be successful. Second part could be misunderstood, but I interpreted in this way:

1. The commit request has been received
2. `pre-merge-commit` runs
3. commit message is prompted
4. ...

After all, this hook, in its default implementation runs the `pre-commit` hook that is in turn called by `git commit`. Especially this last part has made me think that it is not a bug or anything like that, but a design choice.

Comment: Telling the story from the `git commit` perspective explains why the hook is not executed in the first place. I never thought about a bug as git is very mature and somebody else would have run into that issue before. Funny thing is that when you are in manual commit mode, the hook is not executed, too. So, it must be an integrated workflow with no stops.

Comment: I think there are use cases where you want to seperate the merge commit and the merge alone. Does anybody of you have an idea how I can simulate that behavior, e.g. using another hook?

Comment: You could want to keep the two processes separated, but the git team did not provide any explicit hook for that. Most of the time is not necessary and they might have decided to not create a hook for such a specific situation (I do not actually know, mine is just a speculation). Why cannot you commit?

Comment: In general, I want to commit and the hook is executed. But in cases, where the merge fails, I still want to execute some cleanup/other scripts as they do not get executed in the final commit after the merge conflict is resolved. If that would happen, I will be totally fine with the hook. But once the process flow has been canceled due to the merge conflict, it cannot be resumed.